# Value is coming to be null when I am trying to retrieve values in JSON using JAVA

Tags: java, json, pojo

This is my JSON file:

```
{
 "pickEventActivities": [
{
  "orderId": "215",
  "lineNbr": 2,
  "pickByType": "HI",
  "pickGtin": "000",
  "containerId": "52",
  "pickedUser": "testUsr",
  "activations": [
    {
      "activationType": "HI",
      "activationValue": "314"
    }
  ]
}
```

]
}

This is my POJO class:

```
package JsonDiff;

import lombok.Data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Data

class ROOT {
    public PickEvent[] pickEventActivities;
}

class PickEvent  {
    String orderId ;
    String lineNbr;
    String pickByType;
    String pickGtin;
    String ContainedId;
    String pickedUser;
    List<Activation> activations;
}
```

This is my activations class:

```
package JsonDiff;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Activation {
    String activationType;
    String activationValue;
}
```

When I am trying to read the values of the JSON I am getting this:

```
container=null, orderId=null, lineNbr=null, activations=null
```

My Java code where I am reading the json file and printing the value is the following method:

```
   public void comparejson() throws Exception {

    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    ROOT result = objectMapper.readValue(new 
     File("src/test/resources/json/pickevent.json"), ROOT.class);
    for (PickEvent rental : result.pickEventActivities) {
        System.out.println("container=" + rental.containerId+
                ", orderId=" + rental.orderId +
                ", lineNbr=" + rental.lineNbr +
                ", activations=" + rental.activations);
    }
```

But I should be getting the value like this:

```
container=52, orderId=215, lineNbr=2, activations={activationType": "HI, 
 "activationValue": "314"}
```

I am pretty new to this jackson, can someone please help? Thank you

Comment: `PickEvent` class should be annotated with `@Data`. `PickEvent[]` should be `List<PickEvent>`

Comment: @YankLeo I used Data it worked, thanks :)

Comment: @YankLeo I am trying to compare two json files, is there way of comparing it? Can you please suggest any change in the code?

Comment: So basically you are trying to compare two objects then. Just implement hashCode and equal method in all classes to compare. A.equals(B) will start to work then. Google for more help